# white flash when page loads image background

Tags: css

i have a background in the body, in my web page  when it loads,but when it loads
it comes like a white flash behind the background.I know there was a way to fix that with the dreamweaver but i dont know hot to fix it from css or direct in the html page.

but still the white flash comes when it loads.
how to fix it ?
thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you [edit] the question and add the relevant portions of your html file showing the order in which different parts are loading. This will allow people to see what you've done an suggest fact based solutions rather than just guessing what you might have set up.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should set a `background-color` which would be shown before the image is loaded.

In Dreamweaver, you should see it next to the Background Image option

In CSS, that would be: (note black is `#000000`)

```
background-color: #000000;
background-image: url("path/to/image.jpg");
```

Or, in shorthand form:

```
background: #000000 url("path/to/image.jpg");
```

I would recommend using an image editor/color picker to get the main color used in your image.

This question may also help: [Changing the colour of background behind image css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724915/changing-the-colour-of-background-behind-image-css)